# Get desired value of selectbox through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, codeigniter-3

Here i have **three dropdowns** with *differents values* and the code looks like as follows.

To get the value of the corresponding dropdown using jquery i had this but it always gets same value please have a look

```js
$(".one").hide();
$(".two").hide();
$(".three").show();
var  name_type=$("#abc_type_1").attr('name','type');
$("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
$("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');
$("input[name=select_type]:radio").change(function () {
    if($(this).val()=='1')
    {
        $(".one").show();
        $(".two").hide();
        $(".three").hide();

        var  name_type=$("#abc_type_1").attr('name','type');
        $("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
        $("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');
    }
    else if($(this).val()=='2')
    {
        $(".one").hide();
        $(".two").show();
        $(".three").hide();

         var  name_type=$("#abc_type_2").attr('name','type');
        $("#abc_type_1").removeAttr('name');
        $("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');
    }
    else if($(this).val()=='3')
    {
        $(".one").hide();
        $(".two").hide();
        $(".three").show();

        var  name_type=$("#abc_type_3").attr('name','type');
        $("#abc_type_1").removeAttr('name');
        $("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_1">
    <input class="magic-radio" type="radio"  name="select_type" id="1" value="1">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input class="magic-radio" type="radio"  name="select_type" id="2" value="2">
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input class="magic-radio" type="radio"  name="select_type" id="3" checked value="3">
    <label for="3">3</label>
</div>
<div class="left_2 one">
    <select name="type" id="abc_type_1" class="form-control abc_type">
        <option value="A">LSK-A</option>
        <option value="B">LSK-B</option>
        <option value="C">LSK-C</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="left_2 two">
    <select name="type" id="abc_type_2" class="form-control abc_type">
        <option value="AB">LSK-AB</option>
        <option value="AC">LSK-AC</option>
        <option value="BC">LSK-BC</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="left_2 three">
    <select name="type" id="abc_type_3" class="form-control abc_type">
        <option value="super">LSK-SUPER</option>
        <option value="box">BOX-K</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here i want to get the value of the selected select box but i can not get the correct value, please help me to solve.

```
var form_data={      
                    agent_name: $('#agent_name').val(),
                    number: $('#number').val(),
                    number_from: $('#number_from').val(),
                    number_to: $('#number_to').val(),
                    quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
                    amount: $('#amount').val(),
                    date: $('#date').val(),
                    commision: $('#commision').val(),
                    profit: $('#profit').val(),
                    agent_amount: $('#agent_amount').val(),
                    user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
                    type: name_type.val(),
                  }
```

Comment: I don’t see you reading the value of any of those select fields anywhere ...

Comment: What input are you refering to in your code `input[name=select_type`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i updated my question please have a look

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. The only thing that you are ever reading the value of is `input[name=select_type]:radio`, when the change event for that fires.

Comment: @CBroe am reading those values in the remaining code but for simplicity of the program i didn't added it,the value in the `name_type`  is calling

Comment: So you are complaining that you are always getting the same value, but you are not even showing us where you are actually reading this value ... and you think that’s smart? Please go read [ask], and how to create a proper [mcve].

Comment: @CBroe sorry for making you in confuse

Comment: @user_777 i posted answer just replace form_data with new one. If you still gets error let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with script is that you are not handling radio buttons and dropdown while extracting values for posting to server.

**JS**

```
var form_data = {
      agent_name: $('#agent_name').val(),
      number: $('#number').val(),
      number_from: $('#number_from').val(),
      number_to: $('#number_to').val(),
      quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
      amount: $('#amount').val(),
      date: $('#date').val(),
      commision: $('#commision').val(),
      profit: $('#profit').val(),
      agent_amount: $('#agent_amount').val(),
      user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
      type: $("#abc_type_"+$("input[name=select_type]:checked").val()).val()
   };
```

Just replace your form_data with above script. If not works let me know.

This part getting checked value from the radio button.

```
$("input[name=select_type]:checked").val()
```

response is like this. 1 or 2 or 3.

```
$("#abc_type_"+$("input[name=select_type]:checked").val()).val()
```

Now jquery will get value by targeting the ID. eg #abc_type_1, #abc_type_2, #abc_type_3

Answer (score 1):

You add a **default** value to the `inputs` and add **function** that runs when **selects change** like this Code:

```js
$(".one").hide();
$(".two").hide();
$(".three").show();
var name_type = $("#abc_type_1").attr('name', 'type');
$("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
$("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');
$("input[name=select_type]:radio").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $(".one").show();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").hide();

    var name_type = $("#abc_type_1").attr('name', 'type');
    $("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
    $("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');

  } else if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").show();
    $(".three").hide();

    var name_type = $("#abc_type_2").attr('name', 'type');
    $("#abc_type_1").removeAttr('name');
    $("#abc_type_3").removeAttr('name');

  } else if ($(this).val() == '3') {
    $(".one").hide();
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".three").show();

    var name_type = $("#abc_type_3").attr('name', 'type');
    $("#abc_type_1").removeAttr('name');
    $("#abc_type_2").removeAttr('name');
  }
});

$("select").change(function(e){
  alert(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_1">
  <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="select_type" id="1" value="1">
  <label for="1">1</label>
  <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="select_type" id="2" value="2">
  <label for="2">2</label>
  <input class="magic-radio" type="radio" name="select_type" id="3" checked value="3">
  <label for="3">3</label>
</div>
<div class="left_2 one">
  <select name="type" id="abc_type_1" class="form-control abc_type">
            <option value="">Select value</option>
            <option value="A">LSK-A</option>
            <option value="B">LSK-B</option>
            <option value="C">LSK-C</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="left_2 two">
  <select name="type" id="abc_type_2" class="form-control abc_type">
              <option value="">Select value</option>
            <option value="AB">LSK-AB</option>
            <option value="AC">LSK-AC</option>
            <option value="BC">LSK-BC</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="left_2 three">
  <select name="type" id="abc_type_3" class="form-control abc_type">
              <option value="">Select value</option>
            <option value="super">LSK-SUPER</option>
            <option value="box">BOX-K</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks here i used your code but always getting the value of first used `name_type` in passing to the ajax form_data

Comment: check i edited your code and added `alert(name_type.val());` always getting the value of the first select box in that alert

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the current Select Box value

Simplest Example

HTML

```
<select class="select1_class_name" id="select1" data-userid="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
var id = $(this).data('userid');
console.log(id); //you will get on change of selected dropdown
});
```