# can we set attribute with `name `other than `class` or `id`

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all the question will be simple to you but i have a doubt that whether can we use `name` value instead of `id` or `class` like this

```
var name_type=$('.abc_type').attr('name','type');
```

i just tried like this but of no use

```
var name_type=$('input[name=type]').attr('name','type');
```

Comment: As I understand, you want to add a "name=type" to the ".abc_type" classed element?

Comment: "but of no use": of course it isn't you're setting the `name` attribute to value `"type"` on input elements which have a `name` attribute with value `"type"`.

Comment: @DiabloSteve yes that i mean

Comment: Does your code can select the '.abc_type'?
I tried this, and my js can modified name to type.

Comment: @DiabloSteve yes my code can select `.abc_type`

Comment: wich out put you get when do this `console.log(name_type)` after setting the value?

Comment: @Oscar i got like this `length: 3`

Comment: that mean you have 3 element with that name. You can get it in loop or like this: `console.log(name_type[0].value)`

Comment: @Oscar yes that's the thing and 3 element is of select box and the corresponding selected value should be present

Comment: So one of them has the property selected. do you mean something like this in the condition? `name_type[index].find(":selected")`

Comment: @Oscar yes that's it how can we use that

Answer (score 3):

You can unse any of this attribute selectors in Jquery:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
Find which you want to use and then, is the same as get it by `.class` or `#id`

Consider the lenght of the element, because return every element wich has the selector condition.

Use your selector: `var name_type=$('input[name=type]').attr('name','type');`

Then [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943494/how-to-loop-through-array-in-jquery) over that:

```
$.each(name_type, function(index, value){
  console.log("Index: "index + ", Value: "+value);
  if(name_type[index].value == "I want this"){
    //do something or terurn whatever
  }
})
```

Hope helps

Comment: if multiple input fields have same name then how can we fetch the correct value,actually i was stuck in there so i chooses this way but unfortunately using `class` and `id` always getting same value

Comment: can you edit your question and add that casuistics? About your first question, if you iterate over the elements, you can check all the info them... so wich has the the correct value 4u? wich one who the user selected? why you dont identify your inputs with unique `id`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48866731/5064637 here is my question